# Убить — замочить

Tags: жаргон, этимология

На сленге "замочить" означает "убить" (всем памятное "мочить в сортирах"))). А почему именно замочить? Имеется в виду, что человек станет мокрым от крови, или что-то другое?
Благодарю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле "замочить" и "мочить в сортирах" не совсем одно и тоже. Во втором случае  "мочить" не обязательно убивать. Просто хорошо поработать. "Мочи его" на языке шпаны означало избить, стильно поколотить. Какое из двух значений имел в виду Президент, знает наверное только он сам.

А на "высокой фене" мочить, очевидно, от "мокрое дело" - убийство (не обязательно кровавое). Связано, как я понимаю с кровопролитием. Вообще, где-то видел, что "мокрая" на блатном - кровь, но не уверен до конца.

Answer (score 3):

Наверное, по принципу "оставить мокрое место".А от чего оно мокрое - возможны варианты

Answer (score 1):

Старое жаргонное (воровское) выражение. Раньше обычно убивали ножом.
Стоит проткнуть человека ножом, как он сразу же в месте прокола становится мокрым от крови. Поэтому слова "убить" и "замочить" ассоциируются друг с другом.

Answer (score 0):

Liquid (англ.) - мокрый.
Liquidation (англ.) - убийство, уничтожение, упразднение.
Я, конечно, на 100% не уверен, но вот такое совпадение...